# Convert cluster points into a single point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point

I need to try and group cluster points by attribute into one point.  So all points with the same attribute need to be grouped onto 1 location.

Comment: Sorry just to add something, I want to do this in ArcMap

Comment: Have a look at [Central feature tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/central-feature.htm).